# Relativity problem: Lorentz transformation for velocities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

[image]

Does it mean that the observer must be in the same reference frame as the two rods for the two rods to have the same length?

Comment: Each rod sees the other's length as different from its own. The required reference frame sees both rods having the same length.

Comment: Each rod has its own reference frame and so does the observer. So we have a total of 4 reference frames (counting the lab, too).

Comment: In what frame are the rods assumed identical?

Answer (score 1):

Call one rod 1 and the other 2. The rods are identical so in their respective rest frames they have the same length: $L_1=L_2=L$. Let's forget  about $V$ for a second and define the speed of rod 1 in the observers frame $u_1$ and the speed of rod 2 as $u_2$. In this frame the rods appear contracted:
$$L_i=\frac{L}{\gamma_{u_i}}=L\sqrt{1-\frac{u_i^2}{c^2}}$$
where $i=1,2$. So in this frame we have to find $u_1,u_2$ such that $L_1=L_2$. This makes it seem like we have to find two variables but we only have to find one because $u_1=-u$ and $u_2=V-u$. If you can't see why $u_1=-u$ and $u_2=V-u$ you could make a drawing to convince yourself.

The actual answer is really simple though and you might guess just from intuition.

Comment: This might answer the intended question but I don't think it answers the question that was posed.  Rods with the same proper length are not identical in almost any frame.  "Identical" is frame-dependent, and the answer to the question as asked is that the rods are identical in whatever frame they were assumed identical, and it would be a great coincidence if their proper lengths were equal.  This is pedantry if you understand the subject but, I think, the kind of precision that's absolutely necessary for a novice.

Comment: @WillO What do you mean exactly with "the question that is posed"? Do you mean the question that the author intended? I assumed the rods were identical in their _rest_ frame and I believe that this is what the questionmaker intended. The particular frame the question is hinting to is a known frame in special relativity so assuming they are of of equal length in rod 1's frame would be weird.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform :  We agree about what the author (probably) intended.  I claim that a) a literal reading of the question does not clearly convey this intention and b) it is important for novices to be careful about such things.

Comment: PS:  My apologies for getting your screen name wrong in the last comment.  I hope no students  were misled into thinking that a Taylor  expandion is the same thing as a Fourier transform.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @WillO Thanks for your explanation too, but I'm still trying to figure out what you mean, haha...